# Ms Visio 2016 does not display attributes when using Entity Relation Diagram

Tags: visio, erd

When i create an ERD Diagram in Microsoft Visio 2016 The attributes of the table can clearly be seen. After i save the file and the next time i open the document i Can't see the attributes of the ERD tables. what can be seen is Entities with no attribute. but if you select a Design and hover over the designs, the attributes display only when you hover over a design.

This is what i see.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i got for this problem is you first select the entity and click the "HOME" tab and at the top right you will see the following icons

[image]

if you click on "Send to Back" it will make the attributes visible again.